# Date in mmm yyyy format in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column of type timestamp without time zone.

I want to select that column with the `mmm yyyy` format – for example, “Mar 2011”.  How to format it that way?  I tried:

```
select cast(now() as date)
```

but it is giving me the incorrect format.

Answer (score 83):

`SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'Mon YYYY');`

Answer (score 56):

> DateAndTime Reformat:

```
SELECT *, to_char( last_update, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as re_format from actor;
```

> DEMO:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I think in Postgres you can play with formats for example if you want `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
TO_CHAR(submit_time, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as submit_date
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to use a date formatting function for example to_char
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 13):

You can write your select query as,

```
select * from table_name where to_char(date_time_column, 'YYYY-MM')  = '2011-03';
```