# What is the name of the date format and how do I display just the date in html ? Mon Aug 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, datetime, datetime-format

I'm using postgresSQL database. I have added a date column and after inserting a record in pgadmin the date field looks like "24-08-2020". However, when i try to render/ retrieve from database and display in html, the date field looks like this "Mon Aug 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)" . I want to only display the date in this format dd/mm/yyyy. Is there any query in postgres or I should work on js ?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415077/date-in-mmm-yyyy-format-in-postgresql) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert it into unix timestamp and play with that. Use Date class function to take out the day, month and year.

```
const allmonths = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
const day = (d) => {
  if (d < 10)
    return '0' + d;
  return d;
};
const dt = new Date('Mon Aug 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800')
const dtFormat = day(dt.getDate()) + '-' +allmonths[dt.getMonth()] + '-' + dt.getFullYear() // 24-08-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

in postgres you can use to_char to convert a date to your desired format.
e.g.

```
select to_char('24-08-2020'::date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'::text) AS mydate
```

results in

```
24/08/2020
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works inside the pgadmin tool. I get this : "24/08/2020" under the to_char column. However, when I added this query in js there was an syntax error .

Comment: its a query in postgres you have to execute in the backend, where you collect your data, not in js or frontend.